# What is this bug I found at my house?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I found it on my door. I live in Southeast Texas. What is it?

[image: large but in Southeast Texas]

Comment: Can you include more information *in the question itself* (not as a comment). For example, the size, how fast it moved (if at all) time of day, time of year...

Comment: It looks like an insect larva, maybe a dipteran. The white tree-like structures on its side could be its trachea (respiratory system).